# Str.format() for Python 2.6 gives error where 2.7 does not

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting, python-2.6, backwards-compatibility

I have some code which works well in Python 2.7.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sys import stdout
>>> foo = 'Bar'
>>> numb = 10
>>> stdout.write('{} {}\n'.format(numb, foo))
10 Bar
>>>
```

But in 2.6 I get a ValueError exception.

```
Python 2.6.8 (unknown, Jan 26 2013, 14:35:25) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sys import stdout
>>> foo = 'Bar'
>>> numb = 10
>>> stdout.write('{} {}\n'.format(numb, foo))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: zero length field name in format
>>>
```

When looking through the documentation ([2.6](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/string.html), [2.7](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)), I can see no mention of changes having been done between the two versions. What is happening here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Python 2.6 and before (as well as Python 3.0) *require* that you number the placeholders:

```
'{0} {1}\n'.format(numb, foo)
```

The numbering, if omitted in Python 2.7 and Python 3.1 and up, is implicit, see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> *Changed in version 2.7*: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so `'{} {}'` is equivalent to `'{0} {1}'`.

The implicit numbering is popular; a lot of examples here on Stack Overflow use it as it is easier to whip up a quick format string that way. I have forgotten to include them more than once when working on projects that must support 2.6 still.

Comment: Thank you. I was to busy just looking at the documentation for the method itself that I missed the text in the beginning.

Answer (score 5):

This is in the docs here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

About halfway through that section:

> *Changed in version 2.7*: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so `'{} {}'` is equivalent to `'{0} {1}'`.